# Combine strings of data to make a file

Tags: php, arrays, string, file-upload, download

I am currently working with an API that provides a function "GetFileChunk" to pull part of a file using pos and len. There is no documentation so I am experimenting and trying to first pull the file data into an array and then write it out to a file.

As of now I have it reading the data into an array but I am unsure as to how to write it out. I've tried file_put_contents() but this just writes the lines as text rather than creating the file from the byte data.

```
$fm = new FileManager();

$data = array();
$pos = 0;
$len = 32;

//while (($chunk = $fm->getFileChunk('test.cfg', $pos, $len)) != '')
for ($i = 0; $i <= 500; $i++)
{
    $result = $fm->getFileChunk('test.cfg', $pos, $len);
    $chunk = $result->result;

    if ($chunk != '')
    {
        array_push($data, $chunk);
    }

    $pos += $len;
}

var_dump($data);

file_put_contents("test.cfg", $data);
```

Here is what the output looks like when I dump the array afterwards...

```
array (size=49)
  0 => string 'I0FNUCBDb25maWd1cmF0aW9uIEZpbGUNCiMjIyMjIyM=' (length=44)
  1 => string 'IyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIw0KI0RPIE4=' (length=44)
  2 => string 'T1QgRURJVCBXSElMRSBBTVAgSVMgUlVOTklORw0KIyM=' (length=44)
  3 => string 'IyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjDQo=' (length=44)
  4 => string 'DQojIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyM=' (length=44)
  5 => string 'IyMNCiMgU2VjdXJpdHkNCiMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyM=' (length=44)
  6 => string 'IyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIw0KU2VjdXJpdHkuRXhlY1A=' (length=44)
  7 => string 'YXRoPUV4ZWMNClNlY3VyaXR5LkFsbG93Q29uY3VycmU=' (length=44)
  8 => string 'bnRTZXNzaW9ucz1GYWxzZQ0KDQojIyMjIyMjIyMjIyM=' (length=44)
  9 => string 'IyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMNCiMgV2Vic2VydmU=' (length=44)
  10 => string 'cg0KIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyM=' (length=44)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `$data` is an array. `file_put_contents` expects a string (or string-like value). You can `implode('', $data)` to get a string.

Comment: That doesn't really fix the problem. file_put_contents() takes a string, array or stream resource so imploding this into a string is still causing the same issue, the data being written directly as text rather than being used to build the file.

Comment: Why are you putting it in an array in the first place? Why not just concatenate it onto a string?

Comment: What do you mean by "build the file"? What's supposed to be in the file other than the strings you showed?

Comment: Are they encoded and you need to decode them somehow?

Comment: Yeah, this data is encoded, sorry for not being more clear

Comment: Oh, you are reading binary data. It gets base64 encoded. You want to rebuild the binary data, yeah?

Comment: Then call `base64_decode()` after you read it.

Comment: That was all I needed, thanks so much! Should I just close or do you want to post it as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `base64_decode` to decode the chunks after reading them:

```
$data = '';
for ($i = 0; $i <= 500; $i++)
{
    $result = $fm->getFileChunk('test.cfg', $pos, $len);
    $chunk = $result->result;

    if ($chunk != '')
    {
        $data .= base64_decode($chunk)
    } else {
        break;
    }

    $pos += $len;
}

file_put_contents("test.cfg", $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "the data being written directly as text rather than being used to build the file", but I'm going to guess that you want the chunk data, which is base64 encoded, decoded and written to a file. You can use the `base64_decode()` function to do that.

```
php > echo base64_decode('I0FNUCBDb25maWd1cmF0aW9uIEZpbGUNCiMjIyMjIyM=');
#AMP Configuration File
#######
```

You need to do that for each chunk, so your `array_push()` should be:

```
array_push(base64_decode($data), $chunk);
```

With that change your output file should be correct.

But why construct an array, or even a string, before writing to the file? Just decode and write each chunk as it is retrieved:

```
$outfile = fopen('test.cfg', 'w');
.
.
// in your loop..
    fwrite($outfile, base64_decode($data));
.
.
fclose($outfile);
```